# RoR 3.1 - Loading associated objects when querying child with a where phrase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following structure

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :global_lists
end

class GlobalList < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name :globals_lists
    belongs_to :list
end
```

and the following:

```
gl=GlobalList.find(1)   #works 
gl.list                 #works
gm=GlobalList.where(:global_id => 23).includes(:list) #works
gm.list                             # doesn't work
```

How do I access the list when using a where for returning the object?

thx

edit: is there a way for me to flatten this and get all the lists that have this? I guess I could iterate through but have the feeling there might be some syntax that I'm not aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
gm = GlobalList.where(:global_id => 23).includes(:list)
```

returns a collection of models. You need to first the first to get the list.

```
gm.first.list
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `GlobalList.find` returns a single GlobalList object whereas your query with `where` returns an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object (which represents a whole set of objects). You want:

```
gm = GlobalList.where(:global_id => 23).includes(:list).first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GlobalList.find_by_global_id(23).list
```